# Disk error occurred

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, mbr

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside my Windows 8, but after that my Windows 8 is not loading. `a disk error occurred` it says. Then I restored the MBR using boot repair, but again it is showing the same thing. I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Linux too. My suggestion is that making important files backup at first. If you want to have Windows8 and ubuntu at the same time. You can reinstall Windows8 and then use disk manage in Windows8 to format some space for Ubuntu. When you install Ubuntu, choose the installation type to be 'Something else'. Then you can refer to [How to create partitions in Ubuntu while installing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179362/how-to-create-partitions-in-ubuntu-while-installing). Good Luck!