# Ubuntu installation after windows - /root, /home, /swap

Tags: windows-7, root, home-directory, swap, partitioning

I'm still trying to use Ubuntu, so after 3 weeks and few formats I have a new windows and I'm trying to install ubuntu. I'd like to share one partition with windows so I found this [article](https://askubuntu.com/a/179371/335321) and I'm up to make partitions:

I have 280gb ssd, so I made 
161.1 gb ntfs for windows (probably I will resize it later)
104.9 mb ntfs windows made on it's own (what is it?)
48 gb ext4 for ubuntu and software (could I put less?)
2gb swap

and I'd like to make also 28.9 gb ntfs from the rest of the space, however I have already 4 primary partitions as windows made this 104 mb thing. How should I do it?

edit: does it matter if I create them at the end of directory or at the beginning? (order of partitions)

Answer (score 1):

The small ntfs partition is a Windows system partition. If you don't want one to be made, you will need to reformat the drive using something other than Windows, such as the partition utility for Ubuntu.

1. Start the Ubuntu installer and partition the drive. You do not need to get all the partitions fully correct, just the Windows (NTFS). Make sure that you fully partition the drive (you should not leave any free space on the drive). The partition that Grub will be in has to be a primary partition. Windows will most likely want a primary partition as well when it is installing.
2. Apply the partitions to the drive.
3. Cancel the Ubuntu installer
4. Install Windows into the NTFS partition, do not change partitions using the Windows installer. Since there is no empty space of the disk, Windows will put everything into the same partition.
5. Install Ubuntu.

Comment: How big should be these partitions in your opinion?
Should I download 14.04.01, or stay with the 14.04 which I already tried for last couple of weeks?