# Dual Boot formatting partition to ntfs

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I just formatted my PC and decided to install a dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/179371/443406) I set the partitions.

But somehow in the last step I couldn't format the partition using gparted.

I want to have 2 system partitions 50GB each, 1 for windows and 1 for ubuntu, and the rest will be shared.

I mounted them this way.

[image: gparted window]

The partition sda5 should be *ntfs* for using with windows too, but it's locked and I can't unmount. I get

```
Could not unmount /dev/sda5
umount: /home: device is busy.
(In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Comment: You cannot edit or change mounted partitions. The little key symbols show them mounted. So you have to use live installer and gparted from it. But you cannot change /home to NTFS, it must be Linux format. If you want you can shrink it and make another NTFS shared data partition. Also changing format will erase all your data as it is in /home.

Comment: I don't have any data  right now, it's a fresh start. I don't want to shrink the /home, I set 50gb Ubuntu  to that it's not being used. I want to use those 368GB to both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Then you have to either reinstall without the /home partition or move /home back into / (root). For a new user & no important data, reinstall would be easier. But DO NOT use any auto install/reinstall options. Even if it says overwriting Ubuntu partition, it may erase entire drive. But do use Something Else and choose same partition for / as your current partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the advise of [olfred](http://aa):

See the comments above.